# How to fill color of arrow head with dashed line & plain line

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a bezier path dashed line & plain line with the filled arrow.

```
 func addDashed_Arrow(start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, pointerLineLength: CGFloat, arrowAngle: CGFloat) {
        self.move(to: start)
        self.addLine(to: end)
        let  dashes: [ CGFloat ] = [ 7.0, 6.0 ]
        self.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0.0)

        let startEndAngle = atan((end.y - start.y) / (end.x - start.x)) + ((end.x - start.x) < 0 ? CGFloat(Double.pi) : 0.0)
        let arrowLine1 = CGPoint(x: end.x + pointerLineLength * cos(CGFloat(Double.pi) - startEndAngle + arrowAngle), y: end.y - pointerLineLength * sin(CGFloat(Double.pi) - startEndAngle + arrowAngle))
        let arrowLine2 = CGPoint(x: end.x + pointerLineLength * cos(CGFloat(Double.pi) - startEndAngle - arrowAngle), y: end.y - pointerLineLength * sin(CGFloat(Double.pi) - startEndAngle - arrowAngle))

        self.addLine(to: arrowLine1)
        self.move(to: end)
        self.addLine(to: arrowLine2)
        self.lineWidth = 4.0
        self.lineJoinStyle = .round
        self.lineCapStyle = .round
        self.stroke()

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you send which parameter you are passing to function?

Comment: I am send touches began points & touches moved points as start point & end point like

arrow.addDashed_Arrow(start: CGPoint(x: startTouch!.x, y: startTouch!.y), end: CGPoint(x: secondTouch!.x, y: secondTouch!.y), pointerLineLength: 20, arrowAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 5))